# jQuery looped animation for child elements

Tags: jquery, loops, find, jquery-animate

Afternoon all!

I've got a small list of floated divs that I want to highlight one periodically. Basically I'm trying to display a workflow process. Using jQuery I want it to:

1. Get the first child of the parent div (`#general process`)
2. Add a class (i.e  `highlight`) which changes the CSS
3. Add a short delay
4. Remove the `highlight` class
5. Find the next child item (if last to return to the first) and repeat steps 2-4

**I'm trying to scratch my way through this but keep failing. Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this looping animation? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!!**

Here is my current HTML & CSS:

```
<div id="general_process"> 
    <div class="phase"> 
        <div class="number">1</div> 
        <h3>Some title</h3> 
        <p>Content goes here</p> 
    </div> 
    <div class="phase"> 
        <div class="number">2</div> 
        <h3>Some title</h3> 
        <p>Content goes here</p> 
    </div> 
    <div class="phase"> 
        <div class="number">3</div> 
        <h3>Some title</h3> 
        <p>Content goes here</p> 
    </div> 
</div>

#general_process  {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#general_process div.phase {  float: left; padding: 10px 25px; background: #f9f9f9; width: 254px; border: 1px soild #999999;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function (elements) {

    var i = -1;
    var className = 'highlighted';

    if (!elements.length) {
        return false;
    }

    function step() {
        elements.eq(i).removeClass(className);

        if (++i >= elements.length) {
            i = 0;
        };

        elements.eq(i).addClass(className);

        setTimeout(step, 3000);
    }

    step();

}($('#general_process').children()));
```

We use a closure to self-contain all the variables we use to track the state.

We then have a function `step()`, which executes every 3 seconds... it removes the class from the current element, loops back to the first element if we're currently on the last, and then adds the class to the target element.

[View a sexy demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/UnBbF/)

Comment: Matt you are a star! Perfect stuff. Looks like I need to scrub up on some basic JS!!

Comment: Demo is a great touch! Thanks again.